# Failed to import bridging header file in Xcode after Firebase Upgrade

Tags: swift, firebase, bridging-header

I've read many related questions, I tried quite a lot of things, but still, nothing works for me.

I upgraded my Swift App in Firebase and now its in the Firebase Console. The issue is that I've updated the pod file and after that the bridging header file no longer works (not sure why). It causes other issues too, but the main one comes from failing to import the bridging header.

Here's what my pod file has:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'

end
```

Here's what I see as errors:

[image]

In addition, in Project Name > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective C bridging header I've entered (without quotes) "AppName-Bridging-Header.h" and I also tried with the whole path (i.e AppName/AppName-Bridging-Header.h) but it doesn't work.

Again, BEFORE upgrading Firebase pod, it was all working and I had no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Firebase migration API](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/):

Replace the line:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

with

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

and run `pod update` in the project folder

Comment: Forgot to mention that was what I initially did. Tested it again, doesn't work. The same errors appear when I try to build the project

Comment: @Swifter It solved my problem for a while, but now I'm having issues as well. I will update when solved

Comment: @Swifter Did you try `pod repo update`, followed by `pod install` ? solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  inhibit_all_warnings!
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for FCM

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end